# Break up small array into bigger array in arduino for a braille application

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I do not tend to use arduino that much, but this time I got stuck on this part.

What I'm trying to do is a braille translator for a friend of mine which has disabilities and visual impairment. Each column of this array will have a perforation when it encounters a 1

```
int arr[][50] = {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

This is my array which will store all the dots, meaning that 1 its a dot and 0 its a space. My intended result for I don't know  `String str_in="A B C"`
should be

```
int arr[][50] = {
  { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

Every two characters is supposed to be the letter.

But I can only add one letter into the array its replacing the contents and always end in the end letter " C " for example, I know it's probably a wrong for syntax. But I tried many ways without any luck.

I have this method to copy on the Loop body of the code the translated letters into my main array.

```
void copiar(int jj[][2])
{
  for (int letra = 0; letra < 50;) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        arr[i][letra] = jj[i][j];
    letra = letra + 2;
  }
}
```

And to translate each braille character I'm using this method to translate each letter of a string giving the case of the letter.

```
void MatrixB(char a)
{
    switch (a) {
        case 'a': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'b': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'c': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'd': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'e': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'f': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'g': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'h': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'i': {
                int k[][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'j': {
                int k[][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'k': {
                int k[][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'l': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'm': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'n': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'o': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'p': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'q': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'r': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 's': {
                int k[][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 't': {
                int k[][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'u': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'v': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'w': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'x': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'y': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
            
        case 'z': {
                int k[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
                copiar(k);
            } break;
    }
}
```

my loop body has this MatrixB function declared, so each time it encounters a letter it will add it to my main array `arr`using `Copiar()` method

My loop body looks like this:

```
void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= in_str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (String(in_str.charAt(i)) != " ") {
            
            MatrixB(toLowerCase(in_str.charAt(i)));
            printA(arr);
            delay(200);
        }
        else if (String(in_str.charAt(i)) == " ") {
            Serial.println("Aqui va un espacio");
        }
    }
    //printA(arr);
    delay(500);
}
```

the sheet of paper has a limit of 50 characters thats why im doing an array that big. and also because i dont have any idea if there is any other way.

im not expert in arduino code nor C++, so any kind of direction and help will be helpful

Comment: Can you use `std::vector` instead of this mess?

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the code? One note: Using an `int` for an on/off value seems unnecessary. You could use `char` and have the characters printable out-of-the-box.

Comment: This is in dire need of a simple lookup table, especially one that can be configured externally in a text file. What you're doing here with "brute force programming" is error-prone and makes the problem far more difficult to resolve. Remember, a 6 bit value is *just a number*, you don't need to mess around with this array of arrays stuff.

Comment: Don't forget that Unicode (UTF-8) can encode actual [Braille characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns) so you don't even need to work with low-level representations. You can just use the characters instead. This makes debugging a lot easier, plus they can be printed as-is.

Comment: @jabaa One has to download Arduino STL - but it's pretty old and doesn't support proper move semantics.

Comment: Im limited to arduino , because it is what i have on hand.
the main purpose of this mess is to just activate a solenoid when the loop body encounters a " 1 " in the array : )

Comment: You can do that with binary math, it's really simple. Far simpler than an array of array of arrays. `x & (1 << n)` tests if the nth bit is on where n=0 is the least-significant bit. Here your `a` value is just `0b100000`. Easy.

Comment: If you must use an array, I recommend swapping rows and columns.  One row for each perforation.  The problem with Braille is that most things read in by row, when the actual information is usually stored in 2x3 matrices.  This is very similar to the input or displaying of bitmapped fonts (for example, a 5x7 font cell).  You may have to read in 3 rows, then extract the Braille components.

Comment: The problem with arduino braille is the braille display, which must be small enough to be readable by a finger. These are still very expensive. What kind of actuators do you use for display? The characters you can encode with binary bits, one byte per character as in [this example](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/metec-braille-driver/blob/master/include/braille.h).